# setNeedsDisplay calling drawRect on iOS simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having an issue where `setNeedsDisplay` is properly triggering `drawRect` for a UIView subclass when I use the iPad simulator, but not on an actual iPad. I'm using logging to verify that `drawRect` is definitely never being called when the app is running on the device. Any ideas for how this could happen?